# jQuery mobile (phonegap) content width is too narrow

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, width

I am using jQuery mobile in its simplest form.
Just added a page with a header content and footer
in the content I've added many test to get a scroller

The divs seem to be as wide as the word 'test', therfore the scroller only applys to a very small portion of the width of the screen.
When I try to scroll outside of the word 'test' the whole page is moving, without actually scrolling the content area.

I've added the following meta ta g to the head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no;" />
```

it didn't do anything.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c" style="width: 100%">
```

Comment: It didnt really work.
I wrote a simple JS using device.platform to identify the device and overwrite jqm .ui-content class.